# Hide Angular navigation controls if user is not logged in?

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, authorization

Does Angular have a standardized way of hiding controls if the user is not logged in.  We have the `CanActivate` guard which checks to see whether a user can visit a route.  If we hide the route to start with if the user is not logged in or not authorized to access the route?

For example suppose we have a link:

```
 <a routerLink="topsecret">Top secret link</a>
```

We would like to hide this link when the application is rendered, if the user is not logged in.  If the user is logged in and is authorized to proceed to view the `topsecret` component then render the link.

Comment: If you want to know whether user is logged in or not before proceeding to a route, you can use route resolver to call your auth service and find out login status - https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: I updated the question.  Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: You can write a directive or use *ngIf="loggedIn" to hide the link.  You can obtain "loggedIn" flag's value from a service that maintains login state globally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that on your authentication service(instantiated as Auth), you have an attribute named `isLoggedIn` which determines login state.

you can achieve that simply by using `ngIf`:

`<a routerLink="topsecret" *ngIf="Auth.isLoggedIn">Top secret link</a>`